# What Mathematica means by Hashtag?

Tags: differential-equations

I am somehow confused. What Mathematica means by hashtag within the result for my differential equation?

```
DSolve[y'[x] + R*y[x] == T* (y[x])^(-1) + R, y[x], x]
{{y[x] -> 
   InverseFunction[
     ArcTan[(Sqrt[R] (-1 + 2 #1))/Sqrt[-R - 4 T]]/(
       Sqrt[R] Sqrt[-R - 4 T]) + Log[T + R #1 - R #1^2]/(2 R) &][-x + 
     C[1]]}}
```

Comment: See ["What the @#%^&*?! do all those funny signs mean?"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616). It's not a tag, and the octothorp # is (or was) called a pound sign (as in a 50# bag of sand) or number sign (as in the #1 draft pick) in the US, until Twitter used it a special symbol; "hash sign" seems to be chiefly Brit., though again Twitter has spread it around the world, perhaps because the sign has some similarity to hatch marks.

Answer (score 3):

In Mathematica, the hash values are arguments of [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html).

From reference:

```
Function[body]
  or body& is a pure (or "anonymous") function. The formal parameters are # (or #1), #2, etc.
```

In your case it's `#1` and function is:

```
(Sqrt[R] (-1 + 2 #1))/Sqrt[-R - 4 T]]/(
   Sqrt[R] Sqrt[-R - 4 T]) + Log[T + R #1 - R #1^2]/(2 R) &
```

Note the trailing `&`.

Comment: + see also `Slot` in the docs.